# Running a watchService at server start up

Tags: java, watchservice, servletcontextlistener

So i need to run a watchService when the server start up to get the files added in a folder, So i decided to use a Context Listener. Here's a sample code of what i'm trying to do. It's obviously not working, but it summarize what i need :

```
@WebListener
public class StartupClass implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent eve){

        try {
            Path Folder = Paths.get("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test");
            WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            WatchKey key = Folder.register(watchService,StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

            boolean valid = true;

            do {
                WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();

                for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                    WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                    if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                        String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    }
                }
                valid = watchKey.reset();

            } while (valid);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event){
    }
}
```

As you can see, the infinite loop " while(valid " prevent the app from being deployed correctly. so i can't even test it

I need some suggestion and advice on how to properly work this out.
Thanks